# replace missing values based on condition evaluated by grouped data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with columns `Year,` `Exporter`, `Importer` and `TradeValue`.

The Year column contains integers representing years (1970-2010). The Exporter and Importer columns contain character strings representing around 150 countries ("USA", "CAN", "GBR" etc). The TradeValue column contains a mixture of numbers and NAs.

For each Exporter country in each Year, I wish to replace all the NAs for TradeValue with zero but only if there is at least one row which has a non-NA value for TradeValue (for that Exporter in that Year).

Any assistance appreciated.

Edited:

```
> dput(head(df))

structure(list(Year = c(1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L
), Exporter = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), Importer = 
c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola"), 
TradeValue = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could `group_by` `Year` and `Exporter`, replace `NA` to 0's if there is `any` non-NA `TradeValue` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year, Exporter) %>%
  mutate(TradeValue = if (any(!is.na(TradeValue))) 
                      replace(TradeValue, is.na(TradeValue), 0) else TradeValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Running this code results in an error message: Error: incompatible types (NULL), expecting numeric

Comment: @markdavis can you update your post with `dput(head(df))`. It is difficult to debug without a reproducible example.

Comment: @markdavis thanks..can you try the updated version and see if it works?